# Redirect specific get variable to other folder. htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

days ago I seek the solution in tutorials, manuals, forums, ... Still can not find the solution.

I have the following url:

www.example.com/?unsubscribe=31234242424

I need to redirect to:

www.example.com/newsletter/?unsubscribe=31234242424

Only that variable, thanks.

Sincerely, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit a `RewriteRule` based on the content of the `QUERY_STRING` (the bit after the `?`).  You can do this with a `RewriteCond` such as the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} unsubscribe=
RewriteRule ^$ /newsletter/ [QSA,R]
```

The `RewriteCond` matches any `QUERY_STRING` that contains "unsubscribe=".  Then the RewriteRule will rewrite any *empty* request to point to "/newsletter/", and append the query string to it.  Rewriting only an empty request means that requests in subdirectories will not be redirected.

For example

```
http://example.com/?unsubscribe=12345 -> http://example.com/newsletter/?unsubscribe=12345
http://example.com/test/?unsubscribe=12345 : no redirect
```

If you wish to also redirect requests for subdirectories, then replace the rule with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} unsubscribe=
RewriteRule .* /newsletter/ [QSA,R]
```

Hope all that makes sense.

Comment: > **Found**<br>
> The document has moved here.

The link is the same, always gives error that the url has been moved.